# Methods to Cross Compile only defined ("some") Targets in a CMake Project

Tags: cmake, embedded, cross-compiling, googletest, googlemock

I had so far used the well documented way to cross compile code with cmake, defining a Toolchain file like at the end of the post. 
I however would like to find a way of cross compiling not my whole C, C++ Project, but only certain targets. 
A Use case for these is for example when you are doing unit tests with google test for embedded systems and are coordinating everything with CMAKE. 
Can anyone provide a reference, link or minimal example to solve this?

What I dont want to do is to define targets twice for different architectures, I'd prefer to define the toolchain file and somehow passing this to the corresponding CMakeLists.txt or target.

Here is an example of a minimal toolchain file, as I would use it for global configuration of a cmake project.

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ..)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ..)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   C:\,,,.exe)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:\,,,.exe)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  .\build\ghs )

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search 
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Comment: Are you aware of the build mode of CMake? Calling `cmake --build . --target <YOUR_TARGET_NAME> --config Debug` from your build directory after configuring with your toolchain file will build the specified target and config. Unfortunately you can only build a single target at a time.

Comment: when you want to run the unit test, shouldn't you rebuild all targets with the non-embedded compiler ? (not only the cpp files). You will not be able to link embedded C with non embedded cpp.

Comment: @vre do you mean to put the specifics about the cross-compile needs in a custom configuration like debug?

Comment: @sruli Yes, you can do that. Some specifics are provided with the toolchain file, others are described by special targets. Without knowing anything about your build process I just wanted to make sure you know about the build mode of CMake and that it might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project where I want to be able to choose between unit_test and crossCompile. Here is my cmakelist source :

```
if(APP_TYPE STREQUAL "PROJ_UNIT_TEST")
    #compiler choice
    set( ENV{CC} ${CM_ECLIPSE_HOME}/../../MinGW/bin/gcc.exe)


else()
    #CC has to be set before project() that will search for the compiler 
    #this is deprecated : CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
    set( ENV{CC} ${CM_ECLIPSE_HOME}/../../GNU\ Tools\ ARM\ Embedded/6-2016-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe)
```

We pass `APP_TYPE` parameter to choose between the 2 options. I do not use the toolchain file but let cmake search for a compiler in my environment variables automatically.

This may not be the best solution but works for my project

Comment: thanks a lot for the example provided. This indeed works, but I have finally implemented it using a custom build type, since this gives me more flexibility. I will provide a minimal example soon!

Comment: Your example may become usefull very soon for me. Could you please share it ?